# I can't add a class in jquery won't work

Tags: jquery, css

hi everyone i would like to add a class if the user click on a button but he don't want to enter my function. here is the code :

the event ok work he stop at the first line but he won't add a class he jumped into the end of my function directly

```
$("#ok").click(function(){
    $("select option:selected").addClass("chosen");
});
```

ok is my button and chosen is the css class is that correct ? if so do you know why it won't work ?
thanks

Comment: can you please rephrase your question to make it clear..?

Comment: where is your function.please show your complete code.

Comment: Please provide a proper html code?

Comment: I would imagine the class is being added correctly, however styling properties on an `option` element are very limited so the UI is probably not changing.

Comment: how do you know the class not added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this; **http://jsfiddle.net/8pSmr/1/**

***Note***: It won't change the hover colour default - but it will change the option properties;

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku0iA.png]

### Updated

*I noticed in [Neophyte's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2351302/neophyte) answer, that if you changed your selection, it wasn't removing the class to the option, which could cause some UX confusion. This method will remove the option and only have the style given to the only and most recent selected option*

**Javascript**

```
$('button').click( function() {
    $('#options').find(":not(:checked)").removeClass('chosen');
    $('#options').find(":selected").addClass('chosen');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="" id="options">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<button>Confirm select</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.chosen {
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this. it may Help you

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z2DRM/1/)

```
$('#options').change( function() {
$('#options').find(":selected").addClass('chosen');
});
```

Comment: thanks it's exactly my problem but it won't enter in the function i put an alert it won't make it

Comment: What is the `id` of your select?